# How to serialize an XML differently if a tag is CDATA or not?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a very complex XML which I serialize into object, but now we changed some tags which were normal `string` to `CDATA`.

We need to maintain the software retro compatible with old versions, the problem is: I use the serialized object through all code. So is totally unfeasible refactor all the code to work with two different possible serialized objects (one with `CDATAs` and another with `strings`.

The objects is very big so I don't want to 'clone' one to another changing the property kinds.

I would like a way to use the same object but when the serialize will happen identify if the tag is a `CDATA` or a `string` and set to the correct property in the object.

How could I do this?

Comment: Are you only deserialising into your program? The CDATA sections are irrelevant unless you are serialising back to XML afterward.

Comment: @starlight54 I really have no tried do that I will try it

Comment: Should look like this : [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText]
        public string abc;